# hierarchical menu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to do get all hierarchical  menu in wordpress. I am using wp_nav_menu but this function not working as per requirement please check out the below details in array.

[image]

I want to array record set  don't print just need array.

Answer (score 1):

wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu,$args) returns an array of object with properties. You can get the parent id from the object and form your array(post_parent property).